# How to unload jar file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

I have a Tomcat problem, i get this error everytime i try to setup a new server on Eclipse Galileo for my Maven project:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getTempDirectory(Z)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getTempDirectory(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatVersionHelper.getStandardBaseDirectory(TomcatVersionHelper.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat60Handler.getRuntimeBaseDirectory(Tomcat60Handler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.getRuntimeBaseDirectory(TomcatServer.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.editor.ServerLocationEditorSection.initialize(ServerLocationEditorSection.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.editor.ServerLocationEditorSection.createSection(ServerLocationEditorSection.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.editor.ServerEditorPart.insertSections(ServerEditorPart.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.OverviewEditorPart.createPartControl(OverviewEditorPart.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.ServerEditor.createPages(ServerEditor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.findEditor(EditorManager.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2762)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2668)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServerActionProvider$2.open(ServerActionProvider.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

[I found this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933893/tomcat-6-eclipse-galileo) but i don't know what the .jar unload method means... Can someone explain to me? I tried with Galileo SR1 and SR2 but still no luck... :( Can't get my Maven project to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to download the Eclipse Galileo J2EE version. This had the right WTP version.